# How to align an SVG image to the bottom left?

Tags: html, css, image, svg, alignment

I'm having trouble finding any documentation on this.  How can i align a png image, loaded within the SVG tags for scaling purposes.
Right now, the image doesnt move according tot he css, it uses the x and y in the inline svg.  If i delete the x and y out of the svg, it defaults to x=0 and y=0.
  my code:

```
<svg>
 <image class=svgimage xlink:href="././images/Shenron.png" x="0" y="0" height="400px" width="400px">
</svg>
```

```
.svgimage  {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
     }
```

I have a few other SVG elements in the SVG tags but i omitted them here as the code for them is very long.

How do i code this so it always stays at the bottom left of the users browser?

Comment: Please can you add more code: for example the svg element itself

Comment: Setting `y=100%` would probably push the image off the page for starters

Comment: the element im trying to align is that image

Comment: If the only thing in your SVG is the PNG image, then that is totally unnecessary. Including it in an SVG doesn't allow you to do anything you couldn't do with CSS in an HTML page.  In other words, you seem to think an SVG is the solution to your problem, but I suspect you are mistaken. I suggest you describe what you are actually trying to do with the image (your original problem), and we can offer the best solution.

Comment: Its still a valid question hense the upvotes. I need this exact same thing answered. @PaulLeBeau I find your comment unhelpful.

Comment: @Uzer It was an aside comment that only applied under the condition I specified.  If OP had more than just the PNG in his SVG, they were free to ignore my comment.  OP never provided the additional information requested, so never received further help.  If you have a problem similar to this, then post a new question, and link to it from here if you wish. We will try to help.